# Why does a constant function that reads a struct memory cost the same as accessing the struct member directly?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, gas, solidity-0.8.x, optimization

### Context

I have recently introduced a new constant getter in my contract, and I have thought that that it would lead to an increase in gas costs. Below you can find those snippets of code that reproduce the scenario from my actual code repository.

### V1

```
struct MyStruct {
    address owner;
}

mapping(uint256 => MyStruct) internal myStructs;

modifier onlyOwner(uint256 id) {
    if (myStructs[id].owner != msg.sender) {
        revert Foo__NotAuthorized(msg.sender);
    }
    _;
}
```

### V2

```
struct MyStruct {
    address owner;
}

mapping(uint256 => MyStruct) internal myStructs;

modifier onlyOwner(uint256 id) {
    if (getOwner(id) != msg.sender) {
        revert Foo__NotAuthorized(msg.sender);
    }
    _;
}

function getOwner(uint256 id) public view returns (address theOwner) {
    theOwner = myStructs[id].owner;
}
```

### Question

There's also an additional method `getBlockTimestamp` onto which I applied the `onlyOwner` modifier. You can see the full code in this [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/paulrberg/c3a51e1f33255204aa70867ab46e6123).

Now, here's the kicker. V1 and V2 cost the same amount of gas. My question is, why?

I expected V2 to cost more than V1 because it contains the same storage read, but on top of that it involves a call to the public function `getOwner`. Shouldn't that translate to additional opcodes in the bytecode representation of the smart contract?

Does Solidity "inline" the getter function?

Answer (score 3):

Because during compilation these 2 options will be represented as equal bytecode, because makes same logic.

Compiler see that function getOwner get ID and extract owner from mapping, same as 'myStructs[id].owner' line. Later compiler purge all unnecessary steps and makes for this 2 variants of code equal low-level calls.

You can deploy these 2 variants into blockchain, find them on etherscan and click decompilation to see almost human readable representation of how this variants was bytecoded.

> Does Solidity "inline" the getter function?

yes, always when its possible, to maximally reduce future gas-costs for calls